# Background image is not fitting properly iPhone

Tags: iphone

In my application i am using background image programmatically like below

```
self.view.backgroundColor =[UIColor clearColor];

self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"homeScreen.png"]];
```

I have tried both image sizes 320x480 pixels and 640x960 pixels with name of @2x. but both images are not fitting properly into iphone simulator.

Do i need to reduce navigation bar area from 320x480? then it will fit?

I was wondering why?

Comment: if your view contains status bar, then image should be of 480 - 20 (status bar height) = 460 pixels. If it also contains navigation bar then height of your image should be 480 - 20 - 44 (navigation bar height) = 416.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

320 x 480 and 640 x 960 are fullscreen resolutions. if you have a status bar visible remove 20 pixels etc.

Carrier Status bar = 20 high
UINavigationBar = 44 high
UITabBar = 49 high
UISearchBar = 44 high
UIToolBar = 44 high

Comment: Then for High resolution i have to make double of the image? will it be ok with all iphones?

Comment: yes, double the pixels for retina - so have two graphics on the phone image.png and image@2x.png